# How can I implement a pomodoro timer that workers even if the browser is minimized and is able to notify the users

Tags: javascript, laravel, frontend, backend

I need to implement a pomodoro timer to track study sessions for my app. The thing is, javascript setInterval/setTimeout just don't keep running if the browser is minimized.

Even thought I can (do) just use the time that passed since the last interval to calculate the current time, I need a way to notify the user when the browser is minimized.

Thanks in advance!

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:
https://pomofocus.io/

I could kind of get it working with WebWorkers, but still it only kind of fixed the problem, because it only really works on desktops and even then it sometimes just stops.

What I'm trying to do now is having the timer on the frontend and a separate timer on backend. The frontend one uses the WebWorkers and the backend (Laravel) runs every 10 or 30 seconds, only keeps track of minutes passed and send a PushNotification to the client when the next session started or the timer finished.

The problem is that the timers get out of sync pretty quickly and firefox doesn't seem to like showing the notification.

Is there a better way to approach this problem? Maybe keeping the timer only in the backend and using websockets? Any idea is welcome!